# xaringan - can I set a countdown for the whole presentation?

Tags: r, r-markdown, presentation, xaringan

I know I can set a `countdown` for each slide with

```r
---
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    nature:
      countdown: 60000
---
```

But what if I want to time my whole presentation? I mean, I have 15 minutes to present all slides.

Comment: Here you go: https://github.com/gadenbuie/countdown/issues/14#issuecomment-559107293

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the whole presentation, you may just follow Garrick Aden-Bui's answer on GitHub: https://github.com/gadenbuie/countdown/issues/14#issuecomment-559107293

Here is an example: https://bttomio.github.io/slides/25thFMM/slides.html (with files in this public repository: https://github.com/bttomio/bttomio.github.io/tree/master/slides/25thFMM)

Comment: You're welcome, @RxT. I edited my question to add the link for the public repository.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The package `countdown` isn't working on R 4.1. See the timer.html helped a lot!